# Is spotting considered a period?

Tags: menstruation

During perimenopause a womans period may become irregular and lighter. Since menopause is said to be finished after a woman hasn't had a period for 12 months,  would very light menstrual spotting for 2-3 days be considered a period?

Comment: If someone is asking you, simply give them a more detailed answer than yes/no. "It's been 14 months since my last full period, but I had a few days of spotting about three months ago." That's a more useful answer than either "14 months" or "3 months" when asked how long since your last period.

Answer (score 1):

Usually women get a period 2 weeks after ovulation. During menopause hormone levels fluctuate and ovulation may not occur regularly and periods are more spaced out or closer together, heavier or lighter. Some months women do not ovulate at all and don't have a period. There are two main hormones that regulate the lining of the uterus- estrogen ("the fertilizer") and progesterone ("the lawn mower"). During perimenopause women are still producing these two hormones but sometimes they aren't in the same proportion to each other as they were during younger years. If there's more estrogen than progesterone the lining of the uterus thickens and at some point it's shed (spotting) even if there isn't ovulation.

To answer your question, spotting could be counted as a period if you are in perimenopause. However, if you haven't had ANY bleeding for 12 months and then have spotting you should check with your doctor.

Comment: This has the makings of a good answer but it's lacking supporting references. Site policy requires them. They don't have to be exhaustive. A single credible source that supports your main assertions of fact will suffice.